# Adding photos on Google slides from my phone and the app

Tags: google-slides-api

I have a google slide question.  I have added photos from my phone on the google slides app on my phone.  When I open the document on my computers, the latest photos are not showing up.  I have refreshed, restarted all devices, deleted and tried again.  Nothing is working.  Any ideas?

I have expect to see the same photos I've added and see on the google slide from my phone AND computer screen.  I'm definitely working on the same document and have trouble-shooted what I know to try.